# How to get Verbose logging in logcat for a specific module

Tags: android, logging, logcat

One of the android Modules (AudioFlinger) has support for verbose logging (with Tag=AudioFlinger).
Question is how can I see those logs in the logcat?

I did the setprop log.tag.AudioFlinger VERBOSE - but it doesn't seem to work. Do I need to change something and then rebuild the android source again?

Comment: How are you viewing your LogCat output? In eclipse, just the DDMS, or any other way?

Comment: i am using adb shell and then simply logcat. Just to add here, I am able to see other log levels from the same module e.g. LOGE - but just that LOGV is not coming - so I think this is a compile time flag which has to be enabled - just cant seem to find where to enable that

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The logcat documentation doesn't really help. But with more digging I was able to find the answer, as I was expecting the VERBOSE logging is by default OFF at compile time.

Looking at the cutils/log.h helps to find the answer: 
http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/system/core/include/cutils/log.h

```
/*
 * Normally we strip LOGV (VERBOSE messages) from release builds.
 * You can modify this (for example with "#define LOG_NDEBUG 0"
 * at the top of your source file) to change that behavior.
 */
```

So to enable VERBOSE for any source file/module : We have to define LOG_NDEBUG as 0

Answer (score 5):

Use any of the below methods.

```
1) Add or uncomment "`#define LOG_NDEBUG 0`" at top of any module file.
2) In Android.mk or <module>.mk file, add `LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DLOG_NDEBUG=0`

In logcat, logcat | grep -E 'tag1|tag2'.
```

Comment: In `Android.bp` Blueprint files, add `"-DLOG_NDEBUG=0"` to `cflags: []`.