# How to print log messages with in Android framework

Tags: android, java-native-interface, logging, native-code, mediarecorder

I am trying to print log messages within core Android framework files. For example, I tried logging messages within `MediaRecorderClient.cpp` under `frameworks\base\media\libmediaplayerservice\`. I've tried `LOGV`, `LOGE`, `LOGD`, `printf`, and `__android_log_print`, without any success.

Which command should I use to print log messages?

Answer (score 6):

Log should be used, but it will print to logcat not system print.

Example:

```
Log.d("filter", example text); // filter is any tag you want to use as filter
```

You can open logcat in eclipse from window-show view -> other -> android -> logcat

Answer (score 3):

What kind of error do you receive? If it does not compile, make sure you've included <android/log.h>, also in Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
```

If it compiles but does not produce any output, then, like @Warpzit has said, you have to look at logcat to see your messages.

Comment: Apologies for my initial questions, but which Log command should I use?
I've tried to look at logcat with LOGE/LOGV/LOGD but none of my messages show up..

Comment: __android_log_print() should be used.

Answer (score 1):

It also seems that you can only pass a char* to the JNI LOG methods. So if you have numbers in your debug string, you have to put them into a char buffer (with sprintf).

Answer (score 0):

`/system/core/include/cutils/log.h` defines the macros for logging in the Android Framework.

So you uncomment the line that says `#define LOG_NDEBUG 0` at the top of the source file and it will enable VERBOSE logging. You will need to recompile that entire library and put it into your android system.img build.

I believe the macro calls are ALOGV, ALOGE and so on.

It is similar to this other answer:

[How to get Verbose logging in logcat for a specific module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964685/how-to-get-verbose-logging-in-logcat-for-a-specific-module)

Answer (score 0):

First declare string

```
Private String Tag = getClass().getsimplename();
```

and than in your method

```
 Log.d(Tag,"This is my oncreate method");
```