# How to get the position of Item on Click in Android

Tags: android, list, shopping-cart

Hello Everyone!!
                   I am making a sample shopping cart in which i need to get the position of item clicked and get the image displayed on the page on selecting the image from the shopping cart..But here i am getting image of first item only no matter i have clicked another..it is always showing first image of the list...

Here is my code for ProductAdapter.java

```
public class ProductAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private List<Product> mProductList;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private boolean mShowQuantity;

public ProductAdapter(List<Product> list, LayoutInflater inflater, boolean showQuantity) {
    mProductList = list;
    mInflater = inflater;
    mShowQuantity = showQuantity;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mProductList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mProductList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewItem item;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
        item = new ViewItem();

        item.productImageView = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.ImageViewItem);

        item.productTitle = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.TextViewItem);

        item.productQuantity = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewQuantity);



        convertView.setTag(item);
    } else {
        item = (ViewItem) convertView.getTag();
    }


     Product curProduct = mProductList.get(position);


    item.productImageView.setImageDrawable(curProduct.productImage);
    item.productTitle.setText(curProduct.title);

    // Show the quantity in the cart or not
    if (mShowQuantity) {
        item.productQuantity.setText("Quantity: "
                + ShoppingCartHelper.getProductQuantity(curProduct));
    } else {
        // Hid the view
        item.productQuantity.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    return convertView;
}

private class ViewItem {
    ImageView productImageView;
    TextView productTitle;
    TextView productQuantity;
}}
```

And Here is my shoppingcart file

```
public class ShoppingCartActivity extends Activity {

private List<Product> mCartList;
private ProductAdapter mProductAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.shoppingcart);

    mCartList = ShoppingCartHelper.getCartList();

    // Make sure to clear the selections
    for (int i = 0; i < mCartList.size(); i++) {
        mCartList.get(i).selected = false;
    }

    // Create the list
    final ListView listViewCatalog = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewCatalog);
    mProductAdapter = new ProductAdapter(mCartList, getLayoutInflater(),
            true);
    listViewCatalog.setAdapter(mProductAdapter);

    listViewCatalog.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Intent productDetailsIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                    ProductDetailsActivity.class);
            productDetailsIntent.putExtra(ShoppingCartHelper.PRODUCT_INDEX,
                    position);
            startActivity(productDetailsIntent);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Refresh the data
    if (mProductAdapter != null) {
        mProductAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    double subTotal = 0;
    for (Product p : mCartList) {
        int quantity = ShoppingCartHelper.getProductQuantity(p);
        subTotal += p.price * quantity;
    }

    TextView productPriceTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewSubtotal);
    productPriceTextView.setText("Subtotal: $" + subTotal);
}
```

}

ProductActivity.java

```
public class CatalogActivity extends Activity {

private List<Product> mProductList;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.catalog);

    // Obtain a reference to the product catalog
    mProductList = ShoppingCartHelper.getCatalog(getResources());

    // Create the list
    ListView listViewCatalog = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewCatalog);
    listViewCatalog.setAdapter(new ProductAdapter(mProductList, getLayoutInflater(), false));

    listViewCatalog.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            Intent productDetailsIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),ProductDetailsActivity.class);
            productDetailsIntent.putExtra(ShoppingCartHelper.PRODUCT_INDEX, position);
            startActivity(productDetailsIntent);
        }
    });

    Button viewShoppingCart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonViewCart);
    viewShoppingCart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent viewShoppingCartIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ShoppingCartActivity.class);
            startActivity(viewShoppingCartIntent);
        }
    });

}
```

}

Code for ProductDetailsActivity.java

```
public class ProductDetailsActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.productdetails);

    List<Product> catalog = ShoppingCartHelper.getCatalog(getResources());

    int productIndex = getIntent().getExtras().getInt(
            ShoppingCartHelper.PRODUCT_INDEX);
    final Product selectedProduct = catalog.get(productIndex);

    // Set the proper image and text
    ImageView productImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageViewProduct);
    productImageView.setImageDrawable(selectedProduct.productImage);
    TextView productTitleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewProductTitle);
    productTitleTextView.setText(selectedProduct.title);
    TextView productDetailsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewProductDetails);
    productDetailsTextView.setText(selectedProduct.description);

    TextView productPriceTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewProductPrice);
    productPriceTextView.setText("$" + selectedProduct.price);

    // Update the current quantity in the cart
    TextView textViewCurrentQuantity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCurrentlyInCart);
    textViewCurrentQuantity.setText("Currently in Cart: "
            + ShoppingCartHelper.getProductQuantity(selectedProduct));

    // Save a reference to the quantity edit text
    final EditText editTextQuantity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextQuantity);

    Button addToCartButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonAddToCart);
    addToCartButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Check to see that a valid quantity was entered
            int quantity = 0;
            try {
                quantity = Integer.parseInt(editTextQuantity.getText()
                        .toString());

                if (quantity < 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                            "Please enter a quantity of 0 or higher",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Please enter a numeric quantity",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                return;
            }

            // If we make it here, a valid quantity was entered
            ShoppingCartHelper.setQuantity(selectedProduct, quantity);

            // Close the activity
            finish();
        }
    });

}
```

Plz guys Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanx in advance..

Comment: please show us how are you reading the value of index in `ProductDetailsActivity.java`

Comment: @PrafulBhatnagar Thanx Sir for ur response I added the productactivity.java code.

Comment: @PrafulBhatnagar Sir problem is this that it is getting the first that is added to the catalog

Comment: please show how are you reading this value from intent in `ProductDetailsActivity.java`. also check my answer...

Comment: @PrafulBhatnagar Sir i added ProductDetailsActivity.java

Comment: can you please log the value of `position` in `onItemClick` and the value of `productIndex` in the `onCreate()` method of 'ProductDetailsActivity.java' and let us know what are the value you are getting... also what is the size of `mCartList`...

Comment: @PrafulBhatnagar Sir i am not getting the value ..Plz sir dont mind i am very novice for android..

Comment: hoping you know how to print logs in android... if not; this link would help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307583/how-to-print-log-messages-with-in-android-framework... please log the value of position in onItemClick and the value of productIndex in the onCreate() method of 'ProductDetailsActivity.java' and let us know what are the value you are getting... also what is the size of mCartList...

Comment: @PrafulBhatnagar Sorry Sir but i am not getting any value on the class

Answer (score 2):

The `int position` in `onItemClick` gives the position of the clicked item in the array/list you gave to the adapter. 
You can also do getItemAtPosition(); on your listview, if you don't have an easy handle on your original list.

Answer (score 0):

add this code to your Project :

```
 mProductList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 

        {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, 
        View v, int position, long id) 
        {                

            int  h = parent.getPositionForView(v);



            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                    "pic" + (position + 1) + " selected" + h, 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: use : 
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
} 

instead of 
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mProductList.get(position);
}

Answer (score 0):

Just geussig that you have a problematic code where you are reading the index value. Following is the sample code for writing and reading int extra:

To put int value:

```
productDetailsIntent.putExtra(ShoppingCartHelper.PRODUCT_INDEX,
                    position);
```

Following code should be used to read this value in another `Activity`

```
int index = getIntent().getExtras().getInt(ShoppingCartHelper.PRODUCT_INDEX);
```

Hope it helps...