# Cannot move on to a new layout

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Hi I want to move on to a new layout or intent in android java when I press a button.  Currently I have a login_or_register.xml and within it I have a button which has an onclick attribute called menuLogin

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/LogIn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/LOGIN" 
    android.onClick="menuLogin"/>
```

and then in my login_or_register.java I have

```
public void menuLogin(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, login.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

and I want to be able to move to the login layout in which the code goes like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    }
```

I am not quite sure why but when I click the button it does not go on to the new layout.  Oh also within my androidmanifest.xml it looks like this

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.example.ACW.login"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

      <activity
        android:name="com.example.ACW.Login_or_register"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

some extra things are that I have a login.java and a login.xml as well

Comment: is nothing happening? is the `menuLogin` being called for sure? what API level are you using?

Comment: hi cskoala I did as kam said and started the intent on the onCreate method and this worked...however it doesn't work when I put it on the button click

Comment: I don't think the method is being called. You should check by trying to print out a log message.

Comment: I was wondering how you print out a log message...sorry I am rather new to java and android

Comment: look at my answer. It's a different way to handle button clicks but it should work! here's how to print logs for future reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307583/how-to-print-log-messages-with-in-android-framework

Answer (score 0):

try this on `onCreate()`

```
        Intent openMainList = new Intent(StartPoint.this, com.example.kam.MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(openMainList);
```

i hope to help :)

Comment: hi kam this worked however I would like to have it happen on a button click?

Comment: @DorkMonstuh ok put it on `public void onClick(View v){}`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your `menuLogin` method is being called.

To check, you can try to print a log statement in there.

I would try to do something like this:

```
public class MainActivity implements OnClickListener
{
    Button b;
    // whatever else

    public void onCreate(...)
    {
        // ...
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logIn);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
       if (v.getId() == R.id.logIn)
          menuLogin(v);
    }
}
```

Comment: hi cskoala I did log.d() inside however nothing is being printed to logcat within eclipse when I pressed the button

Comment: Yeah, that means it isn't being called.

Comment: however I dont understand why its not being called.

Comment: Did you try what I posted above?

Comment: the xml onClick might not always work. I'm not actually sure how it works since your method has parameters. This is a more reliable way to handle button clicks in my opinion.